# Check if image already available on device (PHAsset)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using `PHImageManager` method `requestImageForAsset`for fetching images from photos. In my case I have to show progress loader if image is present on iCloud, but if images is already downloaded to device then there should not be progress loader. I have collection view in which I am showing all images, on clicking image I am opening details view which shows actual image. When user clicks on image I shows loader, here I need to check if image is present on device or not. Plz suggest a way to do this.

I have checked with progress handler in in `requestImageForAsset` method, but is gets called only when images is need to download from iCloud.